# Matrix entropy measure

Tags: matrices, entropy

I have a matrix (its dimension is $n$ x $m$) where each cell can be $0$ or $1$.

I would like to calculate an *"entropy"* measure on it that tells me how close are the ones together or how spread they are.

For example this matrix:

```
10000000
00000010
00111110
00000010
```

will receive a lower value than this:

```
01101001
00000000
01000100
00100100
```

How can I perform this calculation?

Comment: I would try applying a discrete gradient transform seeing the Matix as a scalar field. It will have nonzero entries in cells where there is a transition.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for an edge detection and approximate your "entropy" as the total length of edges in the $0,1$-Matrix (viewed as a black and white image).
The [Sobel operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) can help you do this.

Check out
$$e(M) := \| \mathcal S(M)\|_F$$
where $\mathcal S$ is the Sobel operator and $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the frobenius norm.